# How to clear header of DataGrid including its rows

Tags: c#, datagrid, datagridview

I have clear the header and rows of `DataGrid` and generate on some button click or some event .
ie.: `ApplicationObjectRecords.Rows.Clear();` is able to clear rows but not header and I tried with  `ApplicationObjectRecords.DataSource=null ;`

Any function similar to this to clear header and create header again?

Comment: hide the datagrid if no data-rows present. That will hide headers too

Comment: try to clear the columns too.

Answer (score 2):

Try `ApplicationObjectRecords.Columns.Clear();`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ApplicationObjectRecords.DataSource=null;
ApplicationObjectRecords.DataBind();
```

It will cause the control to rebind.